# Building a road to a faraway city state - Are they kidding?

Tags: civilization-5

When a really faraway city state asks me to build a road to join our two cities, is this a bug or is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general it isn't worth it, but if you build a city with a harbor nearby, it can be done without a ridiculous expense. Since a harbor extends your trade network the same as a road would, you would then just build a road from the harbor city to the city state.

Comment: I was asking if it was a bug, because, sometimes there are no way to build a road : because of this state is for instance "behind" another civilization. So thanks, indeed, the way to go is the sea :-)

Comment: Easy, just conquer that another civilization ;) At least thats probubly point of view of that CS.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're not hostile, I believe you can make a road through that civilization. Just get an open border treaty. I'm not sure who pays for the roads after they're built though. That I'm still trying to figure out.